# Editing in binary

Tags: vim, binary, hex, reverse-engineering, vi

I've been tinkering with multiple hex editors but nothing really has worked.

What I'm looking for is a way to change a binary in actual binary (not in hex). This is purely for educational purposes and I know it's trivial to convert between both, but I wanted to be able to change the ones and zeroes just like I would do hex.

I've tried using vim with the %!xxd -b but then it won't work with %!xxd -r. I know how to convert the file into binary, but I'm looking for a way to dynamically change it in this format and being able to save it.

Better yet would be if I could find a way to actually create a binary by coding purely in actual binary.

Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vim` or `gvim` should work for you directly, without the `xxd` filter.

Open the file in (g)vim. Place your cursor on a character and type `ga` to see its character code in the status line. To insert character NNN, place your cursor where you want it, go in insert mode and type `Ctrl-v` and then the three digit decimal code value. Use `Ctrl-v x HH` to enter the character by its hexadecimal code.

Make sure your terminal is not set to use UTF8, because in UTF8, typing `Ctrl-v 128` will in fact insert `c280`, the utf-8 encoding of character 128, instead of `80`.

```
LC_ALL=C vim binary-file
```

is the easiest way to make sure you're doing binary character based editing in vim, but that might do weird things if your terminal is utf-8.

```
LC_ALL=C gvim binary-file
```

should open a stand-alone window with proper display.

FYI, if you did want to work in utf-8, `Ctrl-v u HHHH` is how to enter the Unicode character with Hex code point HHHH.

Comment: Really wish there was an easier way to do this to be honest. I know it's not something people really want, in general, but having an actual text editor that had the ability of transforming the entre thing in 1s and 0s and then you could change something and save it easily, would be nice. :D

Comment: Well, my guess is that binary is just too long to display so no one has put the work to develop a direct binary editor or add it as a feature in a hex editor. I can see the value for educational purposes, though.

Answer (score 0):

windows 
open cmd.exe   or notepad++ or whatever editor
enable numlock key
On laptops you need to use the function key or the blue / grey silver numbers above   alphabet keys (using the numbers on the top line will not work as they map to   different scan code.

press alt key + 255 will correspond to 0xff
press alt key + 254 will correspond to 0xfe

see below for a demo

```
C:\>copy con rawbin.bin
 ■²ⁿ√·∙⌂~}─^Z
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\>xxd rawbin.bin
0000000: fffe fdfc fbfa f97f 7e7d c41a 0d0a       ........~}....

C:\>
```

[image: Alt-CHar_in winword]

Comment: Very good to know. Not the answer I wanted but thanks for this information!